# primefaces popup getting closed

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I have to implement the search the functionality in primefaces dialog. After submitiing the search commandbutton the table beside the search needs to get updated. But everytime i am hitting the search button the popup gets closed. Please guide.Below is my code snippet for reference:

```
  ......
  <p:commandButton id="search" value="Search" actionListener="#{createTicketBaseBean.searchUserFromList}" update="@form" onclick="dlg.show()"></p:commandButton>

       </h:panelGrid>

    </h:panelGroup> 
<h:panelGroup style="float:right" >

       <p:dataTable id="table" var="user" value="#{createTicketBaseBean.userList}" selection="#{createTicketBaseBean.selectedUser}" selectionMode="single" rowKey="#{user.email}" >
        <p:column headerText="Name"   >

       <p:commandLink id="nameselect" value="#{user.name}" onclick="dlg.hide()"/>  

        </p:column>

        <p:column headerText="Email">
            <h:outputText value="#{user.email}" />
        </p:column>

        <p:column headerText="Department">
            <h:outputText value="#{user.department}" />
        </p:column>


    </p:dataTable>
```

Comment: Where is dialog? Is it in same `form` as `p:commandButton`?

Comment: yes the above code is of the dialog.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace `onclick` in your `p:commandbutton` with `oncomplete`. `onclick` event is happening immediate when button is clicked. As this is AJAX button (in Primefaces this is default) there will be race conditioning between AJAX request and dialog opening. When using `oncomplete` it will be called after AJAX request is completed.

Comment: I tried but problem still persists. Again the above code is the code that resides inside the dialog. And i need the ajax-submit which would just update my table inside the popup without closing it.

Comment: And where is your `h:form` tag located? Inside or outside `dialog`?

Comment: its outside like this-->><h:form>...<p:commandButton />..<datatable/>...</h:form>.. below is my latest code: <p:commandButton id="search" value="Search" actionListener="#{createTicketBaseBean.searchUserFromList}" update="@form" global="true" oncomplete="dlg.show()"></p:commandButton>

Comment: Hi Partlov, yes its working sorry it wasnt deployed properly my mistake..thanks a lot :-)